# ajax doesnt send FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax

trying to sent ajax post request with FormData, formdata object if ok but ajax wont send it away .
FormData part:

```
            var request_data = new FormData();
        // var request_data = new FormData($("#user_form")[0]); tried this also//
        request_data.append('table', 'students');
        request_data.append('name', $("#name").val());
        request_data.append('email', $("#email").val());
        request_data.append('phone', $("#phone").val());
        request_data.append('check', $("#check").val());
        request_data.append('image', image);
        ajaxCall(request_data);
```

ajax request part:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../src/api.php/InsertTo/",
        dataType: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        contentType: false,
        proccessData: false,
        data: request_data,
        success: function() {
            alert("data");
            $('form').hide();
            $('#post_save').append("Object Successfully Inserted!");
            //call get API //
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        }
```

Comment: Would you check what's server response from api.php/InsertTo/ in network inspection tool?

Comment: it doesnt even send so it show nothing in 'network' it theres something wrong with the way i send it

Comment: If it doesn't send, neither get status code from server... no callback...  you need to add an event when do 'click' to execute ajax call.